# use geometric mean to calculate computer performance

Tags: means

how to use geometric mean to calculate computer performance?
the
 2.2 units The performance of computers COM A and COM B was compared by benchmark using three programs.  When geometric mean is used as the evaluation scale,  The performance of  COM B was twice that of COM A (COM B has better performance). 
 What is the execution time of program 3 in COM B?

```
program | Execution time on COM A (seconds) | Execution time on COM B(sec)
1       |    12                             |9
2       |     6                             |3
3       |    24                             | ??
```

the root is 3
 i thought becuase COM B is 2 times than COM A then
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{9.3.x}}{\sqrt[3]{12.6.24}}=\frac{2}{1}$

but why is the right answer
$\frac{\sqrt[3]{9.3.x}}{\sqrt[3]{12.6.24}}=\frac{1}{2}$?
why is that(?)

Comment: Hint: Performance varies inversely to execution time.

Comment: @Macavity thankyou!! so performance = 1/execution time right??